# Number of $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^a(x) = x+b$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

This is a generalized version of the IMO problem:

> Prove that the function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(f(x)) = x+k$ is nonexistent if $k$ is odd.

Now here is my problem:

> For natural numbers $a,b$, let $$\mathcal{F} = \{f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\mid \forall x \in \mathbb{N},\: f^a(x) = x+b \}$$ (a) Find a neccesary and sufficient for $\mathcal{F} \neq \varnothing$.
> (b) Find $|\mathcal{F}|$. (in terms of $a$ and $b$)

I was able to give proof for (a), by mimicking the solution of the above IMO problem. I think that $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty iff $a\mid b$.

Let $S_i = f^{i}(\mathbb{N}) \setminus  f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N})$, where $S_0 = \mathbb{N} \setminus f(\mathbb{N})$.

**Proposition 1.** $f^{j}(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq f^{i}(\mathbb{N})$ if $i \leq j$.
*Proof.* Since $f^{j}(\mathbb{N}) = f^{i}(f^{j-i}(\mathbb{N}))$ and $f^{j-i}(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, it is pretty clear.

**Proposition 2.** $S_i \cap S_j = \varnothing$ if $i \neq j$.
*Proof.* WLOG $i<j$. Since $S_{i} = f^{i}(\mathbb{N}) \setminus  f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N})$, so $S_i$ does not contain the elements of $f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N})$. However, $S_j = f^{j}(\mathbb{N})\setminus  f^{j+1}(\mathbb{N})$, so $S_j$ is a subset of $f^{j}(\mathbb{N})$, and thus a subset of $f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N})$, by proposition 1. So they are disjoint.

**Proposition 3.** $|S_i| = |S_j|$ for all $i,j$.
*Proof.* It suffices to show that $|S_i| = |S_{i+1}|$. I claim that $f$ is actually a bijection between them. (upon restriction of domain to $S_i$) We know that $f$ is an injection since $f^a$ is an injection. So surjectivity is a problem. Let $x \in f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N}) \setminus  f^{i+2}(\mathbb{N})$, then there exists $y \in f^{i}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $f(y) = x$, by definition. But if $y \in  f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N})$, then $f(y) = x \in f^{i+2}(\mathbb{N})$, contradiction. Therefore $y \in f^{i}(\mathbb{N}) \setminus  f^{i+1}(\mathbb{N}) = S_i$, proving surjectivity. Let's say $|S_i| = n$ for all $i$.

**Proposition 4.** $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty iff $a|b$.
*Proof.* If part is obvious(give $f(x) = x + b/a$). So let's go for only if part. Consider the set $$ \bigcup_{i = 0}^{a-1} S_i = [\mathbb{N} \setminus f(\mathbb{N})] \cup \cdots \cup [f^{a-1}(\mathbb{N}) \setminus  f^{a}(\mathbb{N})] = \mathbb{N} \setminus f^{a}(\mathbb{N})$$ And note that $\mathbb{N} \setminus f^{a}(\mathbb{N}) = \{1,2,\cdots, b\}$ by the condition of problem. However since $S_i$'s are all disjoint, so $\left| \bigcup_{i = 0}^{a-1} S_i \right| = an = b $. Thus $\mathcal{F} = \varnothing $ if $a \nmid b$, completing the proof.

However, I have no idea about (b). Hint for this problem suggests finding a bijection from $\mathcal{F}$ to some easy set, such as a subset of $S_b$ (symmetric group). But what is the set? How can I evaluate the size of $|\mathcal{F}|$?

Thank you for any help, hint, or solution.

Comment: Have you tried figuring it out for some sample numbers and see if you can see a pattern?

Comment: This looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123898

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improvement IMO 1988 $f(f(n))=n+1987$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123898/improvement-imo-1988-ffn-n1987)

Comment: @Karl I read the question and answer. Definitely it is answering my question. But I cannot understand the statement: $$1 = g(f^a(i)) = q_{x_0} + q_{x_1} + \cdots + g_{x_{a-1}}$$ Why is this true? Since $g(f(i)) = g(i) + q_i$, $g(f^a(i)) = g(f^{a-1}(i)) + q_{f^{a-1}(i)}$. Why $q_{f^{a-1}(i)}$ equals $q_{x_{a-1}}$?